# Google plus one button is not working (Google plus one button error)

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus-one

I have setup the Google plus one button on my site.

When I (Or anyone else) clicks the +1 button it adds to the counter for 5 seconds, then red exclamation appears."

Comment: You are the lucky ones that can make it shows up. I put the correct code in my Chrome extension, and boom, it is not working.

Comment: Post the code that you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the page is accessible to Google (i.e. it's not behind a firewall, it's a staging server, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If your site or page is blocked with an htaccess password-protected file then Google can't see it, and it won't let you Plus-One.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happens when you're developping under a localhost, you have to be on a distant server to have it work properly.